# Como crear la opcion de Eliminar en un Arraylist

Tags: java, array, poo, arraylist, herencia

Hola chicos estoy haciendo el siguiente menú con Arraylist las demás opciones me funcionan bien , pero la opción eliminar no me elimina el libro que se solicita solo lo muestra lo que corresponde a la opcion de buscar y mostrar lo he recorrdido con un for each en la opcion eliminar tambien lo use , a continuación muestro el código del menú esperando me puedan ayudar con esa parte

````
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Copia obt = new Copia("disponible","bien","matrix","aventura","alfaguara","2015","2345");
        ArrayList<Libro> Libros =new ArrayList<Libro>();
                         
     int op=0;
    try{
    do{

        op=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nBienvenido a la biblioteca  \n1.solicitar un libro \n2 Mostrar Libro \n3.Buscar libro \n4 Reservar Libro \n5 Eliminar libro"));
        switch(op){
        case 1:
               Validación V =new Validación();
         String titulo=V.LeerLetras("\n Ingrese el titulo del libro");
         String tipo=V.LeerLetras("\n Ingrese el tipo de libro");
         String editorial=V.LeerLetras("\nIngrese la editorial del libro");
         String año=V.LeerNumero("Ingrese el año del libro:");  
         String isbn=V.LeerNumero("Ingrese el Isbn"); 
         Libro obj1 =new Libro(titulo,tipo,editorial,año,isbn);
         Libros.add(obj1);
        break;        
       
```Java
case 2:
         for(Libro aux:Libros){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El nombre del titulo del libro es es:"+aux.getTitulo()+"\n El tipo de libro es:"+aux.getTipo()+"\n La editorial es:"+aux.getEditorial()+"\n El año es:"+aux.getAño()+"\n El ISBN es:"+aux.getIsbn());
        }    
        break;
        
        case 3:
        String buscar="";
         buscar=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Ingrese el nombre del Libro a buscar:");
         for(Libro aux:Libros){
          if(aux.getTitulo().equals(buscar)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El nombre del titulo del libro es es:"+aux.getTitulo()+"\n El tipo de libro es:"+aux.getTipo()+"\n La editorial es:"+aux.getEditorial()+"\n El año es:"+aux.getAño()+"\n El ISBN es:"+aux.getIsbn());
            }
          else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El Libro No existe o ya fue reservado");

          }
               
        }
````

```
case 4:
          obt.Prestar();
         break;
         
        case 5:
             String eliminar="";
         eliminar=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Ingrese el nombre del Libro a eliminar:");
         for(Libro aux:Libros){
          if(aux.getTitulo().equals(eliminar)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El nombre del titulo del libro es es:"+aux.getTitulo()+"\n El tipo de libro es:"+aux.getTipo()+"\n La editorial es:"+aux.getEditorial()+"\n El año es:"+aux.getAño()+"\n El ISBN es:"+aux.getIsbn());
                Libros.remove(aux);
            }
          else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El Libro No existe o ya fue reservado");

          }
               
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Eliminar un elemento mientras recorres la lista por medio de un foreach no es una buena opción, esto genera un comportamiento inesperado. Es más, no necesitas de un bucle para eliminar un elemento, solo debes llamar al método [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) y pasarle el objeto a buscar.

Comment: **Ejemplo:** `Libros.remove(eliminar);` El método retorna `true` si se encontró el elemento, de lo contrario, `false`.